# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have table categories (c) and an another table (x) with a column which can contain cat IDs separated with comma as varchar data type. I want to Select related categories but I'm having error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5,' to data type int." when trying to select:

```
SELECT ID, Title FROM c WHERE ID IN (SELECT catIDs FROM x WHERE ID=any);
```

The subquery returns data like "1,3,4"

Comment: What happens if you replace WHERE ID IN with WHERE CAST(ID as varchar(5)) IN ?

Comment: I agree with @Traroth - list of IDs returned as a string of comma-separated values suggests **a problem with database design**. Is there really the `catIDs` column in the `x` table? Or maybe this is just an example and `1,3,4` is actually returned from stored rpocedure or retrieved from a flat file?

Comment: @Carnotaurus: It's working but not returning right result because it's looking for 'x, y', not 'x', 'y'

Comment: Nice one @Carnotaurus, instead of casting the result of your select into an int cast the ID value to a varchar. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the `1,3,4` string returned by the subquery into separate `int` values. SQL Server does not have a built-in function to do it, but you can use [this user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor/314917#314917).

Create the function `dbo.Split` in your database and then re-write your query as follows:

```
SELECT ID, Title
FROM c
WHERE ID IN
  (
    SELECT s
    FROM dbo.Split(',', '1,3,4')
  )
```

*I replaced the subquery with example results `1,3,4` to shorten the query and make it easier to understand.*

Comment: Yes, I'm going to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor/314917#314917 function. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you actually have values like "1,3,4" in your column catIDs. So you should extract a substring in the select of your subquery.

By the way, I'm not an MS SQL Server expert, but it's probably a bad database design to do so. I'm not sure the RDBMS engine will use indexes in such a case...